# Getting ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 124 and ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 124 error

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to schedule a job Oracle 11g as below but getting the error.
begin

```
sqlplus / AS SYSDBA

SYS.dbms_scheduler.create_job(

job_name=>'testjob',

job_type=>'plsql_block',

job_action=>'BEGIN greetings; END;',

start_date=>SYSTIMESTAMP,

repeat_interval => 'byminute=0; bysecond=5;');

END;

/
```

the error is

```
Error report: ORA-27465: invalid value byminute=0; bysecond=5; for attribute REPEAT_INTERVAL

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 124

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 271

ORA-06512: at line 2
27465. 00000 -  "invalid value %s for attribute %s"
```

*Cause:    An invalid value was provided for the specified attribute.

*Action:   Reissue the command using a valid value for this attribute.

Initially i was thinking its a permission issue so i gave the below permission

GRANT CREATE job TO SYSTEM;

GRANT EXECUTE ON system.greetings TO public;

Could anyone identify the problem?

Comment: Try to delete last ';' in repeat_interval => 'byminute=0; bysecond=5;')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is in the message. Repeat interval is wrong. Check [Calendar Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1013037).

From documentation.

`repeat_interval = regular_schedule | combined_schedule`
It's mean that repeat interval has to be regular_schedule or combined_schedule.

Where `regular_schedule` is

```
regular_schedule = frequency_clause
[";" interval_clause] [";" bymonth_clause] [";" byweekno_clause] ..etc
```

It's mean that frequency_clause is mandatory other are optional.  In your code, there is no frequency_clause.
Working example.
    `repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY; byminute=0; bysecond=5;'`

Comment: Thanks for the understanding

Answer (score 0):

For me

**error:**

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 209 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 594 ORA-06512: at line 2 error

**cause :**

ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired for empty

example while do the truncate that table will show this error

**Solution:**

So needs to clear all locked sessions in DB